# How to measure voice delay between multiple hops

Tags: voip, rtp, pjsip

I am developing a voip solution, where my voice has to pass through 2 hops other than originator of voice before handed over to TDM.

Lets say, Hop A is generating Voice (RTP) and sent to Hop B (it may mix the stream with other streams) and sends to Hop C (it may also do some processing) and hands over the stream to PBX (TDM).

Now how can i measure how much delay is introduced by each hop?

Comment: Are Hops B and C physically on the same? It looks like you need to measure the channel delays and the processing delay. Channel delays require synchronising clocks. The processing delay can be measured with a test signal.

Comment: Hop B and Hop C are physically separate.
I mainly want to measuring network delay.

I tried to sync the clock with NTP, but not accurate. Any suggestions?

If the clock are synced, My idea was to log, RTP packet sequence number to system time on originating and receiving end. Any other better way?

Comment: If NTP is not good enough, what about an iptables rule to send back all the RTP traffic? You would have the same time reference on the log.